# Discord.py message after Django form submission

Tags: django, discord, discord.py

I made a web app using Django and also have a few Discord.py bots running off it.

Up until now I have been using a slash command to submit data and then my bot sends out an embed to several channels stored in my database but I would like to use a form on my web app to submit the data instead.

Is it possible to submit a Django form and then in a view or something have the bot send out messages?

Comment: Sounds like a Modal thing you are trying to do here?